# Highcharts Highstock align x-axis gridlines with center of data point

Tags: highcharts, gridlines

I'm using Highcharts Highstock chart to display daily data.  The vertical (x-axis) gridlines do not align with the data point (gridline is to the left of the data point).  Does anyone know how to align the gridline with the data point?

http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/3/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },

        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: '#000000',
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#000000',
            tickColor: '#000000',
            minorGridLineColor: '#000000',
            minorGridLineWidth: 1,
            minorTickColor: '#000000',
            ordinal: true,
            tickInterval: 86400000,
            minorTickInterval: 86400000
        },

        series: [{
            data:[
                [1417410000000, -0.4818850000000001],
                [1417496400000, -0.40866199999999997],
                [1417582800000, 0.20889499999999994],
                [1417669200000, -0.623542],
                [1417755600000, -0.060399999999999995],
                [1418014800000, -0.56108],
                [1418101200000, 0.30852700000000005],
                [1418187600000, -0.4492829999999999],
                [1418274000000, -0.275211],
                [1418360400000, 0.013063999999999965],
                [1418619600000, -0.27293900000000004],
                [1418706000000, 0.49981200000000003],
                [1418792400000, 0.2362090000000001],
                [1418878800000, 0.4464490000000003],
                [1418965200000, 1.2100639999999998],
                [1419224400000, -0.792635],
                [1419310800000, 0.14788899999999994],
                [1419397200000, 0.011684],
                [1419570000000, 0.08526699999999998],
                [1419829200000, -0.12494599999999997],
                [1419915600000, -0.06489100000000003],
                [1420002000000, 0.279632]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing my date format from ticks to Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd), I can get the data point to align with the vertical grid line.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the [`useUTC`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#global.useUTC) to `false`. Now your Dec 2nd data show on Dec 2nd axis tick. Note that your data is not going to hit every major tick mark - looks like you are skipping weekends but your axis is not.

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't seem to be working.  I want one vertical line for each date.  I want each date's data point to align with the vertical line.  I've set useUTC = false, ordinal: true, and the minor and major tick intervals to be one day (in ticks), but not looking good - [http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/3/)

Comment: By changing my date format from ticks to Date.UTC(yyyy, mm, dd), I can get the data point to align with the vertical grid line.  Only thing left is to not show vertical line on weekends - [http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/kngz3exf/4/)